# getting private key from keystore

Tags: java, keystore, jks

I have `.cer` which is signed by others. from that i create private key file`.jks` using below tool.

`keytool -importcert -file aaa.cer -keystore aaa.jks -alias abcd`

Output:

```
Owner: CN=Sample, EMAILADDRESS=hello@gmail.com, C=IN, OU=Director, O=ABCDEF
Issuer: C=IN, O=ABCDEF, CN=Owner
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Fri Feb 20 17:11:48 IST 2015 until: Mon Feb 19 17:11:48 IST 2018
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  59:9A:1C:FA:F7:F3:45:CA:06:1D:FA:AA:13:B7:68:1C
         SHA1: 3B:4E:4B:5A:57:9E:DC:D6:3E:3C:EB:18:91:60:B6:EA:9D:FB:6E:DA
         SHA256: 37:04:49:08:0A:2E:1D:5D:58:51:0E:69:C3:85:5C:45:55:F0:D9:6B:27:EE:99:6B:E7:08:B7:4A:EA:E0:83:EC
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```

same certificate i need sign on XML for that i wrote below code,

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document inputDocument = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlDoc)));
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("../cer/aaa.jks"), "xxxxxxx".toCharArray());
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry =(KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("abcd", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("xxxxxxx".toCharArray()));
X509Certificate x509Cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();
X509Certificate x509Cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance(MEC_TYPE);
Reference ref = fac.newReference(WHOLE_DOC_URI, fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null), Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED,(TransformParameterSpec) null)), null, null);
SignedInfo sInfo = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,(C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),Collections.singletonList(ref));
KeyInfo kInfo = getKeyInfo(x509Cert, fac);
DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(),inputDocument.getDocumentElement());
XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(sInfo,kInfo);
signature.sign(dsc);
Node node = dsc.getParent();
Document signedDocument = node.getOwnerDocument();  
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
trans.transform(new DOMSource(signedDocument), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
```

But I'm getting Exception at line no 6.

stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: trusted certificate entries are not password-protected
    at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(Unknown Source)
```

please help how to fix this problem thanks.

Comment: Don't post output pictures here. Copy and paste the *text.* It's easy enough. Otherwise you're wasting other people's bandwidth; reducing legibility; eliminating further co py/paste; and generally reducing your chances of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `.cer` file only contains the public key together with some signing-information from the CA, so you don't have a private key in your keystore to retrieve. What you did with importing the `.cer` file is to add it to the set of certificates your JVM will trust.

What you need to make this work is the private-key-file that was used to generate the certificate-signing-request for this certificate. If it wasn't created in a java-keystore using keytool you might have to do some extra-steps since you can#t directly import private-key and certificate into a `.jks`-file but e.g. have to create an intermediate PKCS12-keystore. Using openssl it might work like this:

```
# Create PKCS12 keystore from private key and public certificate.
openssl pkcs12 -export -name myservercert -in certificate.cer -inkey server.key -out keystore.p12
# Convert PKCS12 keystore into a JKS keystore
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore mykeystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias abcd
```

Comment: what is `server.key` file here? sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: It's the pem-file containing the private key - but you might also already have it in a jks-file. Your main-challenge at this time is to somehow find out where your private key is kept.

Comment: If I have the private key file, the pem file, what should be done with it?